# How to show both pregenerated html and an image in JSP?

Tags: html, image, jsp, dynamic, text

OK, here is the problem I have. I have a servlet that dynamically creates an image (not based on parameters) which I do NOT want to save on the HDD.

I also have a HTML template (JSP) where I want to show that picture.

I create my image as following:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PieDataset dataset = createDataset();
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset, "OS Usage");

    resp.setContentType("image/png");
    ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(resp.getOutputStream(), chart, 500, 400);

    req.getRequestDispatcher("report.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

My JSP looks like this:

```
<body>
    <h1>OS usage</h1>
    <p>Here are the results of OS usage in survey that we completed.<br>
    <p><img alt="OS usage" src="/reportImage">
</body>
```

When that code is executed, I get what I expected, from the way I wrote my code, a image only, without any html.

My question is how to do it so the HTML renders as well.

Thx.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? If you're only targeting the modern set then you'll be able to use data-uri (http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/).  The other thing to do is to write one servlet for the image and one for the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have two servlets:

- One to generate the HTML page (by forwarding to a JSP). This generated page contains `<img src="/reportImage" .../>`. When the browser sees this tag, it sends a second request, to the URL `/reportImage`.
- One to generate the image, mapped to the `/reportImage` URL. This servlet should only send the bytes of the image to the response output stream. It must not forward to a JSP.

Answer (score 0):

declare count=0 in your servlet.. if u get image then increment the count value.. now tha value is 1.. in your jsp code put one condition if count==1 show that img else hide the

tag